# HTTPSSLERROR:chrome web driver cannot be installed under Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, ssl, openssl, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Python and Selenium. My main idea is when I start the application, it will automatically open a chrome browser. It worked fine on my computer: Windows 10, Chrome version: the latest - 120.0.6099.110

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument(
    '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.41 Safari/537.36')


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)

url = "https://redeem.tcg.pokemon.com/en-us/"
browser.get(url)

print("Please log in manually. The script will continue after you have logged in.")
WebDriverWait(browser, 300).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "code")))

start_app()
browser.quit()
print("Exiting...")enter code here
```

However, when my friend tried to use his computer to open the application, he got the following:
request.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host="googlechromelabs.github.io",port=443:Max retries

[image]

I searched online and found people add the following two lines to bypass the SSL_Verfiy

```
os.environ['WDM_SSL_VERIFY'] = '0'
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

I have tried but still did not work out.
Btw, he is using VPN. But even if I am using a VPN as well, it worked fine on my computer. I guess it might be due to firewall or local network issue(but he said he has already closed the firewall). I am wondering if there is any other way to solve the problem. Thank you so much. Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: It clearly says that it fails to reach the host to download the driver. So yes, it might be a firewall or local network issue - which means that it has nothing to do with your script, can not be fixed by ignoring SSL errors or similar. Make sure the site is accessible from your system first.